# Is primefaces 3.3.1 a stable and reliable version of primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, namespaces, primefaces

Hi I want to know whether primefaces 3.3.1 is a stable version or not?

**EDIT**
I found that the problem was in the namespaces when I changed namespace uri from primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui to primefaces.org/ui primefaces components worked properly.

Comment: you really could not google this ?

Comment: Which thing makes you ask this question? Please must put some references when you ask something like this.thx

Comment: I newly changed my primefaces version from 2.2 to 3.3.1 and found that tab were not displayed in proper tab format. But I found that the problem was in the namespaces  when I changed namespace uri from http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui  to  http://primefaces.org/ui tabs were displayed properly.

Comment: You should ask a concrete question about **that** problem instead of asking such an overly generic question which would only lead to debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Every release that is not being suffixes with *rc* (release candidate) or *SNAPSHOT* or *M* (milestone I think) for example 3.4rc1 is considered to be a stable and reliable

(of course the there might be bugs here and there)

---

**B.T.W**

When you have some anomalies caused when migrating from one P.F version to another take a look at the [Primefaces MigrationGuide](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide)